# ¿Cómo puedo registrar los errores usando Application_Error excluyendo los 404?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Uso log4net para registrar los errores de mi aplicación, todos los errores intencionales de mi aplicación tienen una pequeña "bandera" al inicio del mensaje, de tal manera que cuando suceden puedo evitar registrarlos en el log, dejando el control del registro al método que lo lanzó.

Lo anterior tiene la intención de nunca mostrar un error al usuario más que el HTTP 404, inclusive los errores no controlados, los cuales son enviados al registro de log4net.

Sin embargo veo que cuando (ahora si) no existe un archivo estático (por ejemplo) en mi aplicación se lanza el evento Application_Error y me lo registra.

Este es mi código:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Encontrar los errores que no se deben registrar.
    var indicatorOfNotLog = NotFoundResult.ShortCode;

    // Obtener el último error generado en la aplicación.
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();

    // Determinar que errores se registrarán en el el registro.
    if (!(exception.Message.Length >= indicatorOfNotLog.Length && exception.Message.Substring(0, indicatorOfNotLog.Length) == indicatorOfNotLog))
    {
        Log.Fatal("Error no controlado.", exception);
    }
}
```

Por ejemplo me registra estos errores:

`System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): No se encuentra el controlador de la ruta de acceso '/Content/imge.css'`

¿Cómo puedo hacer para excluir los errores que sean por archivos o rutas no encontradas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes validar el tipo de exception

[How to: Handle Application-Level Errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3.aspx)

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();

  if (exc.GetType() == typeof(HttpException))
  {
      return;
  }

  //aqui log del problema
  Log.Fatal("Error no controlado.", exception);

  Server.ClearError();
}
```

o sea comparando por el `HttpException` puedes hacer que pase de largo el control del evento